# Laravel adding a role to a newly created user

Tags: php, laravel, crud, roles, user-management

I am creating a new user from my already made CRUD, however, I don't know how I can also assign a role to the user we are creating. I am working with Laravel and 3 tables. I have 1 table that is my users table, 1 table that is my roles table, and 1 table that is my bridge table between roles and users. I have this made because my users can have more than 1 role assigned to themselves.

My question now is how do I give the user a role and how do I save the user to all the tables I mentioned before. Please remember I am working from a crud, so I have a create view.

Greetings and thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have a look at the [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method for eloquent relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have these tables:

- `users`
- `roles`
- `role_user`

Where `role_user` has a `role_id` and a `user_id` column. Then your models would look something like:

```
class User extends Model
{

    /**
     * Roles relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Role extends Model
{

    /**
     * Users relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

And because it's a `BelongsToMany` relation, you would use the `sync` or `syncWithoutDetaching` methods to add or synchronise user roles. Or `attach()` for adding a single role to a user. For example:

```
// The $role variable can be a model instance, or an ID of the role.
$role = Role::all()->random();
$user = User::all()->random();

$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching($role);

// or
$user->roles()->attach($role);
```

I would recommend looking at the documentation for managing the relations ([link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)). Because `sync` for example removes relations that aren't provided in the given array of models or ID's to synchronise - which would result in an unexpected behaviour if you aren't aware of this behaviour.

Comment: Goodmorning, I worked your possible solution out, however I now get the error 'user_id cannot be null' when submitting the newly created user. What can I do about this? @Alserda

Comment: When using `$user->roles()->attach()` (or `sync` or `syncWithoutDetaching`, the `user_id` on the role_user column is set via the relation. So maybe you're missing a part in the definition of your `roles` function on your User model?
Can you provide some more context, such as the part where you're creating the user?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the solution written above.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, then you can mark my reaction as 'the answer'. Welcome to StackOverflow!